# How to reverse SSH tunnel to remote docker container for Xdebug?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, ssh, xdebug

There are many posts on SO and elsewhere on how to set this up. So far I've been unsuccessful in getting it working.

**Setup**
Local machine - Windows 10, with Cygwin, git bash, and WSL2 with Ubuntu installed; and MacBook Air (Mojave)
Host machine - AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2
Docker container - CentOS 7.8 running PHP with Xdebug

**Goal**
Remotely debug PHP code in container from local machine by utilizing a reverse tunnel from the local machine to the container.

I have gotten this working before when the PHP code was installed locally on the host machine, so the question is not around Xdebug. As soon as I moved the PHP code into the container, debugging no longer works.

**What I've tried**
Setting up a reverse tunnel from the local machine to the host EC2 instance works. For this I'm doing `ssh -vvv -i "aws.pem" -R 9000:localhost:9000 user@ec2instance` in terminal, cygwin, or git bash and testing with `nc -z localhost 9000 || echo 'no tunnel open'` on the host machine.

When I `docker exec -it container bash` into the container and run nc, the tunnel is not available.

I'm using docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: 'privateregistry/project/container:latest'
    restart: always
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
      - '447:443'
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www/project'
```

I have tried with and without mapping the 9000 port. I have tried variations of the ssh tunnel:

`ssh -vvv -i "aws.pem" -R :9000:localhost:9000 user@ec2instance`
`ssh -vvv -i "aws.pem" -R 0.0.0.0:9000:localhost:9000 user@ec2instance`
`ssh -vvv -i "aws.pem" -R \*:9000:localhost:9000 user@ec2instance`
`ssh -vvv -i "aws.pem" -R 9000:172.20.0.2:9000 user@ec2instance` (container IP)

I've also tried using `ssh -L` with no luck.

Several posts, like this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/881240/ssh-reverse-tunnel-into-docker-container) suggest adding `GatewayPorts yes` on the host machine. I've tried this as well with no change.

I have not tried using `--network=host`, primarily due to security concerns. I also would rather not use ngrok, as I'd like to be able to use localhost or `host.docker.internal` for the `xdebug.remote_host` setting.

For completeness, here is what I have for Xdebug:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

Comment: Not a SSH expert or Amazon EC2 user, but few point anyways: 1) what web server/PHP runner do you use there? If it's php-fpm then it uses the same TCP 9000 port by default. I suggest to use 9001 or alike instead for Xdebug comms to avoid any possible conflicts. 2) Reverse SSH runnel means that on the target end (server or inside the container if that's where the SSH end is) you connect locally and SSH does the rest by forwarding it to your local PC. So if your SSH tunnel ends up inside the container, I would expect to see `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1`

Comment: Here is one article that is about "normal" SSH and PhpStorm. But you can use it to see how it all works in general and see if you can take any useful info for your actual setup: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: I'm also not super sure about this: `- '9000:9000'` -- what does it do exactly? How is works with SSH in your setup? As I understand this tells that the Docker uses port 9000 for accepting incoming connections on that port and forwarding it into inside the container (on the same port). Is this for SSH so it can connect into the container? Just in case, my point is that it's Xdebug that initiates connection to your IDE/editor and not other way around. Such line is not needed for local Docker containers (as IDE/editor cannot listen on that port then).

Comment: I am using php-fpm, but using unix socket, not TCP port. I did try with and without the port mapping. It does make sense that it should not be needed. I'll take a closer look at that article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working. After reading up on the ssh man page and looking over things again, I realized I was binding to the docker container IP not the bridge (docker0) IP.

I updated my connect command to `ssh -vvv -i "aws.pem" -R 9000:172.17.0.1:9000 user@ec2instance` with the right IP and the tunnel started working. I do still have GatewayPorts enabled (per the man page) and removed the 9000:9000 mapping.

I then updated my xdebug.remote_host value to the same IP and debugging is now working. Not sure why host.docker.internal didn't work, but that's for another day.