# Why can't I use PhpStorm with Xdebug on a remote server with Docker

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to get Xdebug 2.9.8 working on a Docker container running on remote server. I am trying to debug using port 9000. I am using Bitnami php-fpm.

```ini
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.idekey=docker
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

I am setting the `remote_host` to 172.17.0.1 which I got from **ifconfig** (not run in the container).

I get the following from Xdebug log:

```
[38] Log opened at 2021-09-28 20:40:52
[38] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.17.0.1:9000.
[38] W: Creating socket for '172.17.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[38] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[38] Log closed at 2021-09-28 20:40:52
```

I am able to set breakpoints. But the program execution just never stops at my breakpoints. What am I doing wrong?

I have run the following to set up port 9000:

```
ssh -i "rst-staging.pem" -R 9000:localhost:9000 ubuntu@ec2-35-153-28-164.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: This is likely a firewall issue.

Comment: What does PhpStorm's debugger validation tell you about this?

Comment: Thanks Derick. At the server or at my laptop? I can't imagine how my laptop  could be listening if it can't directly be addressed?

Comment: Nico, that is not working. I have told jetBrains techs that and was told that doesn't matter. I agree with you. I need to dot the i's and cross the t's. The validation tool gets a status code 404. But I seem unable to set the Path to create a validation script.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62587772/783119 -- may give you some hints (seems related to me: Xdebug, Docker, AWS, SSH tunnel).

Comment: Yes, Lazy, I saw that. I therefore changed opening the port to: ssh -i "rst-staging.pem" -R 9000:172.17.0.1:9000 ubuntu@ec2-35-153-28-164.compute-1.amazonaws.com  But it seems to have no affect. It is the error in the xdebug log that has me worried.

Comment: Can you SSH into that container (to run some commands)? Are you sure that it's PhpStorm process that listens on a local TCP 9000 Xdebug port? Use `netstat` or alike to ensure that (have "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm enabled so it listens for incoming debug connections). The idea is: enable that and then check the connection from your remote server using `telnet` or alike utility -- just need to see if it will connect or not. If it's not connecting -- well, either SSH tunnel is not good or it's a firewall (local/AWS/Docker network settings).

Comment: Thanks Lazy. I am able to get the debugger going as long as I change the link on the landing page to http://172.17.0.1:81. Normally this should be https but I was told that https doesn't work with IP addresses. That is a little frustrating since I feel that I need to protect the app (which runs at port 81) with https. I will however be protecting access to the web app  (at port 81) with oauth.

Comment: It works with http but not https. Is it possible that xdebug will not work with https?

Answer (score 0):

php.ini file in the container should contain the following:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug

xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

Within the container, the output of `php -v` should show that the Xdebug is enabled.

```
PHP 8.0.23 (CLI) (built: Sep 13 2022 11:09:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.23, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

In Intellij or PHPStorm, under **Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug**,
make sure that the value of the xdebug debug port is set to `9001,9003`, which is the default.

Also, make sure that a server with correct path mappings is added under,

**Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers**